# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: kotlin, api, retrofit

Не могу разобраться. При компиляции выдаёт такую ошибку:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.parseapi, PID: 17925

И это всё, что он пишет. Помогите разобраться.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import com.example.test_lern.repository.Repository


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val repository = Repository()
        val viewModelFactory = MainViewModelFactory(repository)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.getPost("Крылов")
        viewModel.myResponse.observe(this, Observer {
            response ->
            Log.d("Response", response.userName.toString())
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы абсолютно уверены, что в logcat нет больше никакой информации об ошибке?

Comment: Попробуйте переключить Logcat на Warn,Verbose,Info etc... Там должна быть ваша ошибка